# NgControl in Directive: No Provider for NgControl

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Directive which I would like to inject 'NgControl' but got 'No provider for NgControl' error.

My File Directory is as following:

```html
app folder
 |--directives folder
        |--myDirective
 |
 |--components folder
        |--events folder
             |--event.module.ts
             |--event1 folder          
                 |--event1.compoenent.html <-- where I use myDirective, which is a reactive form
                 |--event1.component.ts
        
 |--app.module.ts
 |--custom-material.module.ts <-- where I declare my myDirective
```

my directive:

```js
import { Directive, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: "[myDirective]"
})
export class myDirective implements OnInit{

  constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ngControl.control.valueChanges.subscribe(
      value => {
          console.log('xxx');
      }
    );
  }

}
```

my custom-material.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ myDirective ],
  exports: [
    myDirective
  ],
})
export class CustomMaterialModule { 

}
```

Comment: Where are you putting `myDirective` on? `NgControl` has to be provided by someone. In my experience its either the reactive forms or template driven forms directives that do so, think `ngModel`, `formControlName` and `formControl`

Comment: @realappie Thank you for reply, I updated my question above. I put myDirective in a reactive form.

Comment: Please check the usage of the directive. The field should have an associated `[formControl]` or `formControlName`

Comment: @dmd Can you show me how you are using it? The folder structure is not helping me under the issue.

Comment: @realappie I got the problem, because I place it on the <form> tag(which has formgroup), but not on <input> tag (which has formControlName). Thank you!

Comment: @SachinGupta Thank you for the tip! I got the problem as I said above. Thank you!

Comment: @dmd Tip, if you don't want your directive to throw that error whenever you are injecting `NgControl` you can use the `Optional` decorator. This is useful in case someone in your codebase uses the directive without knowing its dependency on a forms directive, in that case you can throw a more descriptive error or even link to this stackoverflow post :D You would do so by checking the presence of `ngControl` yourself. Think `if (this.ngControl == null) { console.warn('descriptive error..') } `

Comment: @realappie Thank you very much for the tip, Optional is a good idea! I will do that, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this constructor in your directive..

```
  constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {}
```